# There's a site that puts designers and developers together, what is it?

Tags: design, development

I remember a site (the design is a dark color scheme, Helvetica Neue type and purple accents if I recall correctly) that would put designers and developers together for specific projects.

Anyone have any idea what site I'm talking about?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer.

http://builditwith.me/

Comment: http://programmermeetdesigner.com/ is another one along these lines.